# Featured questions API

Tags: feature-request

Can we get an API to get the list of featured questions (`/questions/featured`)?

Comment: Update: [/questions/featured](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions) was added as an API route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?sort=featured

Comment: Doh! It's actually mentioned in the `questions` documentation. :-/ Though, it does seem strange to use the `sort` parameter for filtering. Also, it makes it impossible to get the list of featured questions sorted by another criteria (expiration date or bounty size for example - both important considerations for the bounty hunters).

Comment: @Franci, yeah, agree for that wording, you could convince them to rename it with some explanations. :-)

Comment: @Franci, bounty questions are not too many, so grep them all and process them in client would be ok IMHO, (not sure about there is seperate parameters or not though)