# In API 2.0, what happened to questions sorted by "featured?"

Tags: support, status-completed, api-v2

I was looking for a way to grab the list of "featured" questions via the API, and I stumbled across several answers that all point to the same solution:

[Shouldn't there be a separate call for featured questions?](https://stackapps.com/questions/625/shouldnt-there-be-a-separate-call-for-featured-questions)

[Featured questions API](https://stackapps.com/questions/132/featured-questions-api)

The solution seems to be "call the questions endpoint, with sort=featured"

This doesn't appear to be supported by API 2.0, however:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?order=asc&sort=featured&site=stackoverflow

```
 {"error_id":400,"error_name":"bad_parameter","error_message":"sort"}
```

Has this been removed, or superseded by some other API call?  (Or am I just doing something wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ball got dropped on that one.

Basically, `featured` was a wierd sort so it was removed as an option against `/questions` and similar.

It is now available as [/questions/featured](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions) (and [/users/{ids}/questions/featured](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions-on-users)).